# for _ in range . как работает нижнее подчеркивание

Tags: python, циклы

```
matrix = [[[0]*5] for _ in range(5)]
```

есть такое выражение, создает пять таких элементов `0 0 0 0 0`. Кто может объяснить саму механику создания, чем проще тем лучше.

К примеру

```
for x in range(5):
    print (x)
```

`range(5)` - это 0,1,2,3,4

и для каждого значения начиная с первого (0) выполняется действие `print(x)` (выводит на экран текущее значение, в данном случае 0), после чего берется следующее значение, пока они не закончатся. в итоге на экране мы имеем:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

Желательно в таком ключе объяснение, а то я не понимаю суть этого выражения, что означает это нижнее подчеркивание?

Answer (score 14):

Нижнее подчёркивание это такое же допустимое имя переменной, как и `x`, например.

То есть, с точки зрения интерпретатора, выражения `for _ in range(5)` и `for x in range(5)` ничем не отличаются и будут выполнятся одинаково.

Просто по традиции нижнее подчёркивание используют для того, чтобы показать, что эта переменная нигде дальше не используется. То есть мы используем какую-то синтаксическую конструкцию, в которой требуется создать новую переменную, но нам нужна не эта переменная, а какие-то другие эффекты от данной синтаксической конструкции.

Выражение `for _ in range(5)` обычно используется просто для того, чтобы повторить что-то 5 раз. На каждой итерации переменная `_` будет принимать последовательно значения 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, но нам эти значения не нужны, нам нужно только чтобы произошло пять итераций. Поэтому мы и даём имя переменной `_`, так как это традиционное обозначение ненужной переменной.

Теперь относительно того, что вообще происходит в вашем выражении.
Само выражение вида `[что-то for переменная in последовательность]` - это так называемое списковое включение (в оригинале - list comprehension).

На самом деле оно просто представляет из себя сокращённый синтаксис такого цикла:

```
res = []
for переменная in последовательность:
    res.append(что-то)
```

Умножение массива на число создаёт массив, в котором исходный массив повторён несколько раз. Соответственно, `[0]*5` - это всего лишь краткая запись для `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`

Соответственно, с учётом вышесказанного, ваше выражение полностью эквивалентно такому коду:

```
matrix = []
for _ in range(5):
    matrix.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

Comment: Допишите `for` в конструкциях вида `_ in range(5)`, иначе это будет не повторение 5 раз, а проверка попадания значения переменной в диапазон от 0 до 4.

Comment: @insolor, действительно, не подумал об этом.

Answer (score 4):

Нижним подчеркиванием обычно обозначается переменная, имя которой нам не важно, так как мы ее не используем.

Как можно заметить, в строке

```
matrix = [[[0]*5] for _ in range(5)]
```

Значение `_` нигде не используется, просто в результате каждому элементу в соответствие ставится массив из 5 элементов.

Comment: правильно ли я понял, что при этом _ заменяется на значение которое было перед ним, к примеру
7 далее пишем _ * 3 и получаем 21, так как _ заменилось на 7,

Comment: @allay, нет, `_` ни на что не заменяется. Это самостоятельная переменная, точно такая же как и тут `for x in range(5):`, на каждой итерации `_` будет принимать значение из указанного интервала.

Comment: @allay, переменная `_` ничем не отличается от любой другой переменной. Ее использование в качестве получателя "ненужных" значений - просто договоренность.

Comment: @insolor, технически, `_` — это _слегка_ особенная переменная, поскольку в интерактивном режиме она хранит результат последнего выражения.

Comment: @diversenok, это не свойство переменной в языке, и даже не в реализации языка, а просто то как используется эта переменная в конкретном инструменте - REPL. Вполне можно реализовать другой REPL, например, в котором результат вычисления никак не сохраняется.